# We found that your app does not follow the iOS Data Storage Guidelines

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

We found that your app does not follow the iOS Data Storage Guidelines, which is required per the App Store Review Guidelines.

In particular, we found that on launch and/or content download, your app stores 3.05 MB. To check how much data your app is storing:

Install and launch your app

```
Go to Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup > Manage Storage
```

If necessary, tap "Show all apps"
Check your app's storage
The iOS Data Storage Guidelines indicate that only content that the user creates using your app, e.g., documents, new files, edits, etc., should be backed up by iCloud.

Temporary files used by your app should only be stored in the /tmp directory; please remember to delete the files stored in this location when the user exits the app.

Data that can be recreated but must persist for proper functioning of your app - or because customers expect it to be available for offline use - should be marked with the "do not back up" attribute. For NSURL objects, add the **NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey** attribute to prevent the corresponding file from being backed up. For CFURLRef objects, use the corresponding **kCFURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey** attribute.

For more information, please see Technical Q&A 1719: How do I prevent files from being backed up to iCloud and iTunes?.

It is necessary to revise your app to meet the requirements of the iOS Data Storage Guidelines. If you have difficulty reproducing a reported issue, please try testing the workflow described in Technical Q&A QA1764: How to reproduce bugs reported against App Store submissions.

If you have code-level questions after utilizing the above resource, you may wish to consult with Apple Developer Technical Support. When the DTS engineer follows up with you, please be ready to provide:

complete details of your rejection issue(s)
screenshots
steps to reproduce the issue(s)
symbolicated crash logs - if your issue results in a crash log

here is my code

```
static NSString *rootDir = nil;
    if (rootDir == nil) {
        NSArray *rootPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        rootDir = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/OfflineData", [rootPath objectAtIndex:0]];
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:rootDir]) {
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:rootDir withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:NULL];
        }
    }
    return rootDir;
```

Comment: Need more information to answer your question, just posting apple mail comment won't help. Also the code which you added is not the exact cause.
When the app is opened first time, Are you copying any content to the documents directory ? If yes, then that's the cause.

Comment: I have also code like`if (!self.recipeDatabase) {
        NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
        url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Default Database"];
        self.recipeDatabase = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];
    }`

Answer (score 2):

> **Library/** This is the top-level directory for any files that are not
> user data files. You typically put files in one of several standard
> subdirectories. iOS apps commonly use the Application Support and
> Caches subdirectories; however, you can create custom subdirectories.
> Use the Library subdirectories for any files you don’t want exposed to
> the user. Your app should not use these directories for user data
> files. The contents of the Library directory (with the exception of
> the Caches subdirectory) are backed up by iTunes. For additional
> information about the Library directory and its commonly used
> subdirectories, see The Library Directory Stores App-Specific Files.
>
> **tmp/** Use this directory to write temporary files that do not need to
> persist between launches of your app. Your app should remove files
> from this directory when they are no longer needed; however, the
> system may purge this directory when your app is not running. The
> contents of this directory are not backed up by iTunes.

Read [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) for more information

You shouldn't put these kind of files in Library, instead you can use temporary directory \tmp:

```
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@", [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString], @"OfflineData"];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName]];
```